# Convert data.frame single (hierarchical) column to multiple columns using Index

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame. I'm calling him trouble

```
> head(trouble)
            ID              Category
1    1.NA.NA.NA.NA                     A
2  1.1.NA.NA.TOTAL         Total under A
3   1.1.1.NA.TOTAL Of Which in 1s period
4   14.NA.NA.NA.NA                     B
5 14.1.NA.NA.TOTAL              No as B1
6   14.10.NA.NA.NA                And B2
```

I want to use the hierarchical information hidden in trouble$ID (variable). 
Look closely!

```
> head(look[,c("ID.1", "Category", "Group")],6)
         ID.1              Category Group
1  1.NA.NA.NA                     A  <NA>
2   1.1.NA.NA         Total under A TOTAL
3    1.1.1.NA Of Which in 1s period TOTAL
4 14.NA.NA.NA                     B  <NA>
5  14.1.NA.NA              No as B1 TOTAL
6 14.10.NA.NA                And B2  <NA>
```

Above is out initial trouble$ID got separated on last delimiter (".") and renamed as ID & Group.

Now, I can go through columns of `trouble` by hand to convert it to something like this :

```
ID          CategoryI   CategoryII     CategoryIII             Group
1.NA.NA.NA  A           <NA>           <NA>                    <NA>
1.1.NA.NA   A           Total under A  <NA>                    TOTAL
1.1.1.NA    A           Total under A  Of Which in 1s period   TOTAL
```

`So my question is:` How can I do this automatically?

`Samples:` Here is the link to access sample [`trouble`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vXyRKQAIBZpSEDq-bPnQxh5-Co76ekZkekn2uv8aFa0/edit#gid=0) & his [`output`](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10J1cqGPTsVZxpw-0LrFQUiOZ-Tfjg2Rr51NfDNkiCO4/edit#gid=0)

PS: This is more than splitting a single column to multiple columns. Pls don't get confused.

Comment: Can you provide the first 6 rows of the modified dataframe `trouble` in order to better understand what you want to do?

Comment: Thanks @F.Privé, links to sample data is now available.

Comment: so trouble and look are the same thing, and ID / ID.1 are the same thing ? I don't get it

Comment: Yes @Moody_Mudskipper,
we are going from trouble to look to output.
Problem is to automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(magrittr)

trouble <- read.table(text="ID              Category
1    1.NA.NA.NA.NA                     A
2  1.1.NA.NA.TOTAL         'Total under A'
3   1.1.1.NA.TOTAL 'Of Which in 1s period'
4   14.NA.NA.NA.NA                     B
5 14.1.NA.NA.TOTAL              'No as B1'
6   14.10.NA.NA.NA                'And B2'",stringsAsFactors = FALSE,header=TRUE)

look <-
  trouble$ID %>%
  strsplit("\\.") %>%
  lapply(function(x){c(paste(x[1:4],collapse="."),x[5])}) %>%
  do.call(rbind,.) %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  setNames(c("ID.1","Group")) %>%
  cbind(trouble,.)

# ID              Category        ID.1 Group
# 1    1.NA.NA.NA.NA                     A  1.NA.NA.NA    NA
# 2  1.1.NA.NA.TOTAL         Total under A   1.1.NA.NA TOTAL
# 3   1.1.1.NA.TOTAL Of Which in 1s period    1.1.1.NA TOTAL
# 4   14.NA.NA.NA.NA                     B 14.NA.NA.NA    NA
# 5 14.1.NA.NA.TOTAL              No as B1  14.1.NA.NA TOTAL
# 6   14.10.NA.NA.NA                And B2 14.10.NA.NA    NA

get_3_cat <- function(v){c(v[1],paste(v[1:2],collapse="."),paste(v[1:3],collapse="."))}

look_and_codes <- look[,1] %>% 
  strsplit("\\.") %>% 
  lapply(get_3_cat) %>%
  do.call(rbind,.) %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  setNames(paste0("code",1:3)) %>%
  cbind(look,.)

look_and_codes$IDclean <- gsub("\\.NA","",look_and_codes$ID.1)

# ID              Category        ID.1 Group code1 code2    code3 IDclean
# 1    1.NA.NA.NA.NA                     A  1.NA.NA.NA    NA     1  1.NA  1.NA.NA       1
# 2  1.1.NA.NA.TOTAL         Total under A   1.1.NA.NA TOTAL     1   1.1   1.1.NA     1.1
# 3   1.1.1.NA.TOTAL Of Which in 1s period    1.1.1.NA TOTAL     1   1.1    1.1.1   1.1.1
# 4   14.NA.NA.NA.NA                     B 14.NA.NA.NA    NA    14 14.NA 14.NA.NA      14
# 5 14.1.NA.NA.TOTAL              No as B1  14.1.NA.NA TOTAL    14  14.1  14.1.NA    14.1
# 6   14.10.NA.NA.NA                And B2 14.10.NA.NA    NA    14 14.10 14.10.NA   14.10

output <- look_and_codes %>% merge(look_and_codes[,c("IDclean","Category")] 
%>% setNames(c("code1","CategoryI")) %>% unique,all.x=TRUE) %>%
  merge(look_and_codes[,c("IDclean","Category")] %>% setNames(c("code2","CategoryII")) %>% unique,all.x=TRUE) %>%
  merge(look_and_codes[,c("IDclean","Category")] %>% setNames(c("code3","CategoryIII")) %>% unique,all.x=TRUE)

#        code3 code2 code1               ID              Category        ID.1 Group IDclean CategoryI    CategoryII           CategoryIII
#   1    1.1.1   1.1     1   1.1.1.NA.TOTAL Of Which in 1s period    1.1.1.NA TOTAL   1.1.1         A Total under A Of Which in 1s period
#   2   1.1.NA   1.1     1  1.1.NA.NA.TOTAL         Total under A   1.1.NA.NA TOTAL     1.1         A Total under A                  <NA>
#   3  1.NA.NA  1.NA     1    1.NA.NA.NA.NA                     A  1.NA.NA.NA    NA       1         A          <NA>                  <NA>
#   4  14.1.NA  14.1    14 14.1.NA.NA.TOTAL              No as B1  14.1.NA.NA TOTAL    14.1         B      No as B1                  <NA>
#   5 14.10.NA 14.10    14   14.10.NA.NA.NA                And B2 14.10.NA.NA    NA   14.10         B        And B2                  <NA>
#   6 14.NA.NA 14.NA    14   14.NA.NA.NA.NA                     B 14.NA.NA.NA    NA      14         B          <NA>                  <NA>

clean_output <- output[,c("ID.1","CategoryI","CategoryII","CategoryIII","Group")]
clean_output <- clean_output[match(clean_output$ID.1,look_and_codes$ID.1),]

#          ID.1 CategoryI    CategoryII           CategoryIII Group
# 3  1.NA.NA.NA         A          <NA>                  <NA>    NA
# 2   1.1.NA.NA         A Total under A                  <NA> TOTAL
# 1    1.1.1.NA         A Total under A Of Which in 1s period TOTAL
# 5 14.10.NA.NA         B        And B2                  <NA>    NA
# 6 14.NA.NA.NA         B          <NA>                  <NA>    NA
# 4  14.1.NA.NA         B      No as B1                  <NA> TOTAL
```

Comment: `Trouble` consist of 25 rows and `clean_output` have 65 row.
Merge starts to duplicate the rows of original data set. This comes as big challenge.
Can you think of any way to remove duplicated rows here ?

Comment: You probably have duplicated rows in your trouble tables (at least duplicated for the columns we're using). Make a copy of trouble for only the columns we're using here, and try `trouble <- unique(trouble)`. Tell me if it changes something. If not I'll need a reproducible example.

Comment: output line has been corrected, no duplicates anymore and works with linked data

Answer (score 0):

This is a challenging problem. The solution below uses `zoo::na.locf()` (*last observation carried forward*) and grouping after reshaping the data from wide to long format with `data.table`'s `melt()`.

The solution should be easily adaptable to an arbitrary number of columns. There are only two places where the number of `Category`columns is hardcoded.

```
library(data.table)   # CRAN version 1.10.4 used
# define column names
Cats <- paste0("Cat", 1:4)
# create new columns by splitting ID
setDT(trouble)[, (c(Cats, "Group")) := tstrsplit(ID, ".", fixed = TRUE)]
# amend ID as requested by OP: 
# remove Group part from ID, keep only first 4 parts
trouble[, ID := stringr::str_extract(ID, "^(\\w+[.]){3}\\w+")]
# add row number
trouble[, rn := .I]
# reshape from wide to long
long <- melt(trouble, measure.vars = c(Cats, "Group"))
# replace "NA"
long[value == "NA",  value := NA]
# find level of each row
long[variable %in% Cats & !is.na(value), level := last(variable), rn]
# create new category column, fill with known values
long[variable == level, new := Category]
long[variable == "Group", new := value]
# fill remaining NAs where appropriate, keep NAs at begin of each group
long[order(variable, rn), new := zoo::na.locf(new, na.rm = FALSE), 
     .(variable, rleid(value))]
# reshape from long to wide
result <- dcast(long, rn + ID ~ variable, value.var = "new")[, rn := NULL][]
result
```

which returns:

```
             ID          Cat1          Cat2                  Cat3                Cat4                       Group
 1:  1.NA.NA.NA             A            NA                    NA                  NA                          NA
 2:   1.1.NA.NA             A Total under A                    NA                  NA                       TOTAL
 3:    1.1.1.NA             A Total under A Of Which in 1s period                  NA                       TOTAL
 4: 14.NA.NA.NA             B            NA                    NA                  NA                          NA
 5:  14.1.NA.NA             B      No as B1                    NA                  NA                       TOTAL
 6: 14.10.NA.NA             B        And B2                    NA                  NA                          NA
 7:  14.10.1.NA             B        And B2             Then B2.1                  NA                          NA
 8:   14.10.1.1             B        And B2             Then B2.1                Male                    Children
 9:   14.10.1.1             B        And B2             Then B2.1                Male                      Adults
10:   14.10.1.2             B        And B2             Then B2.1              Female                    Children
11:   14.10.1.2             B        And B2             Then B2.1              Female                      Adults
12:   14.10.1.3             B        And B2             Then B2.1 Total {(9) to (12)}                    Children
13:   14.10.1.3             B        And B2             Then B2.1 Total {(9) to (12)}                      Adults
14: 16.NA.NA.NA Month Positon            NA                    NA                  NA                          NA
15:  16.1.NA.NA Month Positon        Group1                    NA                  NA                          NA
16:   16.1.1.NA Month Positon        Group1              Group1 A                  NA Balance From Previous Month
17:   16.1.1.NA Month Positon        Group1              Group1 A                  NA             Stocks Received
18:   16.1.1.NA Month Positon        Group1              Group1 A                  NA              Unusable Stock
19:   16.1.1.NA Month Positon        Group1              Group1 A                  NA           Stock Distributed
20:   16.1.1.NA Month Positon        Group1              Group1 A                  NA                 Total Stock
21:   16.1.2.NA Month Positon        Group1              Group1 B                  NA Balance From Previous Month
22:   16.1.2.NA Month Positon        Group1              Group1 B                  NA             Stocks Received
23:   16.1.2.NA Month Positon        Group1              Group1 B                  NA              Unusable Stock
24:   16.1.2.NA Month Positon        Group1              Group1 B                  NA           Stock Distributed
25:   16.1.2.NA Month Positon        Group1              Group1 B                  NA                 Total Stock
             ID          Cat1          Cat2                  Cat3                Cat4                       Group
```

#### Data

The OP has provided input data and expected result via download links.

```
trouble <- structure(list(ID = c("1.NA.NA.NA.NA", "1.1.NA.NA.TOTAL", "1.1.1.NA.TOTAL", 
"14.NA.NA.NA.NA", "14.1.NA.NA.TOTAL", "14.10.NA.NA.NA", "14.10.1.NA.NA", 
"14.10.1.1.Children", "14.10.1.1.Adults", "14.10.1.2.Children", 
"14.10.1.2.Adults", "14.10.1.3.Children", "14.10.1.3.Adults", 
"16.NA.NA.NA.NA", "16.1.NA.NA.NA", "16.1.1.NA.Balance From Previous Month", 
"16.1.1.NA.Stocks Received", "16.1.1.NA.Unusable Stock", "16.1.1.NA.Stock Distributed", 
"16.1.1.NA.Total Stock", "16.1.2.NA.Balance From Previous Month", 
"16.1.2.NA.Stocks Received", "16.1.2.NA.Unusable Stock", "16.1.2.NA.Stock Distributed", 
"16.1.2.NA.Total Stock"), Category = c("A", "Total under A", 
"Of Which in 1s period", "B", "No as B1", "And B2", "Then B2.1", 
"Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Total {(9) to (12)}", "Total {(9) to (12)}", 
"Month Positon", "Group1", "Group1 A", "Group1 A", "Group1 A", 
"Group1 A", "Group1 A", "Group1 B", "Group1 B", "Group1 B", "Group1 B", 
"Group1 B")), .Names = c("ID", "Category"), row.names = c(NA, 
-25L), class = "data.frame")

output <- structure(list(ID = c("1.NA.NA.NA", "1.1.NA.NA", "1.1.1.NA", 
"14.NA.NA.NA", "14.1.NA.NA", "14.10.NA.NA", "14.10.1.NA", "14.10.1.1", 
"14.10.1.1", "14.10.1.2", "14.10.1.2", "14.10.1.3", "14.10.1.3", 
"16.NA.NA.NA", "16.1.NA.NA", "16.1.1.NA", "16.1.1.NA", "16.1.1.NA", 
"16.1.1.NA", "16.1.1.NA", "16.1.2.NA", "16.1.2.NA", "16.1.2.NA", 
"16.1.2.NA", "16.1.2.NA"), CategoryI = c("A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "Month Positon", 
"Month Positon", "Month Positon", "Month Positon", "Month Positon", 
"Month Positon", "Month Positon", "Month Positon", "Month Positon", 
"Month Positon", "Month Positon", "Month Positon"), CategoryII = c(NA, 
"Total under A", "Total under A", NA, "No as B1", "And B2", "And B2", 
"And B2", "And B2", "And B2", "And B2", "And B2", "And B2", NA, 
"Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1", 
"Group1", "Group1", "Group1", "Group1"), CategoryIII = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Then B2.1", "Then B2.1", "Then B2.1", "Then B2.1", 
"Then B2.1", "Then B2.1", "Then B2.1", NA, NA, "Group1 A", "Group1 A", 
"Group1 A", "Group1 A", "Group1 A", "Group1 B", "Group1 B", "Group1 B", 
"Group1 B", "Group1 B"), CategoryIV = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Total {(9) to (12)}", 
"Total {(9) to (12)}", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), Group = c(NA, "TOTAL", "TOTAL", NA, "TOTAL", NA, NA, 
"Children", "Adults", "Children", "Adults", "Children", "Adults", 
NA, NA, "Balance From Previous Month", "Stocks Received", "Unusable Stock", 
"Stock Distributed", "Total Stock", "Balance From Previous Month", 
"Stocks Received", "Unusable Stock", "Stock Distributed", "Total Stock"
)), .Names = c("ID", "CategoryI", "CategoryII", "CategoryIII", 
"CategoryIV", "Group"), row.names = c(NA, -25L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: @AakashDhondiyal I appreciate your feedback, it was quite a though question, indeed.

Comment: Thanks. 
Wonderful solution - Actually you solution reminds me of famous lion's claw metaphor.

If you are not aware about it then, do read Johann Bernoulli's mathematical challenge at (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Later_life_of_Isaac_Newton)